# Convert VHDX to VHD (Get-VHD and Convert-VHD are not recognized)

Tags: powershell, azure, vhd

I wanted to convert some VHDX files to VHDs so that I can upload them to Microsoft Azure as I have to migrate some Servers to the Cloud for a company. The problem is, that my Server seems to not know the VHD commands in the PowerShell.

```
Get-VHD : The term 'Get-VHD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-VHD -Path * | %{Convert-VHD -Path $_.Path -DestinationPath ($_.Pa ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-VHD:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

and

```
Convert-VHD -Path ".\VHDName.vhdx" -DestinationPath ".\VHDName.vhd"

Convert-VHD : The term 'Convert-VHD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
    program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Convert-VHD -Path ".\Windows 8.1 x86 Update1 UpdatePack Upgrade.vhdx" ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Convert-VHD:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Has anyone got an idea how to fix that? Hyper-V can't be installed, VirtualBox neither.
The Server itself is a Windows 10 Technical Preview 3 VM hosted on Azure. The Version of Powershell is 5.0.10514.0.

Comment: What do you mean "Hyper-V can't be installed" ? If you have a .vhdx file, Hyper-V is *already* installed.

Comment: Nope. The VHDX files are uploaded for further processing. The Scenario is like this: there is a Hyper-V Server in an office in Germany, I am located in Austria. The Company in Germany want's to migrate their VMs to Azure, and thus they are uploading the VHDX files to my Server which I am using to convert the disks and then to create the VMs on Azure. Also, the server that stores the VHDX files is a Guest in an Hyper-V Hypervisor (managed by Microsoft)

Comment: This information isn't related to the question at all. If you have a VM with vhdx files, you have Hyper-V already. Even if you use a desktop host, the technology is still Hyper-V. The [Convert-VHD](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848454(v=wps.620).aspx) command *is* available in Windows 8 and the RTM of Windows 10, as long as in the corresponding servers.

Comment: You aren't trying to convert the vhdx file from inside the VM itself?

Comment: No, of course not. The VHDX files were uploaded to a virtualised server where I can not enable Hyper-V. the Convert-VHD command is not available inside this VM and thus I can not convert the files. Since we are talking about multiple files at about 150GB, I don't want to reupload them.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this limitation in a couple of environments. The issue is that if you are using VMware, you have to make certain configuration changes in what your processor allows the OS to see/utilize (you can google how to enable this), however, if you are already in the MS cloud, they don't seem to keen on setting the appropriate flag to allow you to install/enable Hyper-V FULLY, which you NEED to be able to use the commands on Windows server.

Like someone alluded to in another post and I can confirm that it works is that on Windows 10 (at least Professional) you have to enable the WINDOWS FEATURE will all options selected (will require a reboot). Even if you cannot enable Hyper-V at the top level, you can still use the VHD commands in PowerShell without issues or limitations.

In the "Turn Windows features on and off"
Expand Hyper-V
Select: Hyper-V Management Tools (this should select all)
Expand Hyper-V Platform
Select: Hyper-V Services (will require a reboot).

With these options, you can run the Hyper-V commands as needed.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of powershell installed on your system? Convert-VHD cmdlet is supported only on PS V4.
Otherwise if for some reason your PS module for hyper-V is not installed, you can download and import the module for Hyper-V from this link:
http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/

Updates:

you need enable hyper-v first

cmd for your reference:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```

Comment: I'm running PS V5.0.10514.0, and since this is a VM in Hyper-V, I can't install Hyper-V. As of now, I've found out how to install the modules, but I am now getting Convert-VHD : The operation on computer 'SVR' failed: Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Convert-VHD -Path ".\...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Convert-VHD], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ConvertVhd


Any idea? a

Answer (score 0):

You could also try it with Virtualbox. First open a Powershell and go to the installation folder.

> cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"

Then try

> .\VBoxManage.exe convertfromraw "C:\Users\username\your\path\file.VHDX" "C:\Users\username\your\path\file.VHD" --format VHD